# Reverse engineering option in Visual studio 2008 arch edition

Tags: c#

We have visual studio 2008 architecture installed and a c# solution created. We need to generate UML diagram (showing the classes,  the relationship between them etc). In the architecture edition we don't see any option that would generate such diagram. The option of class digram mearly generates the class diagram but do not show such relationship.
Is anyone aware of this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK UML diagrams are non existent in VS 2008
They should be available in VS 2010

Best bet here: download a tool that can import the existing code and create diagrams
try Enterprise architect-  http://www.sparxsystems.com/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visio 2003 or Visio 2007 to generate UML diagrams from within Visual Studio.

Also note, not sure what relationships you're looking to see, but any property that references an object, you can right-click and pick 'Show Association', which will connect those on the diagram.

Also also, you can download the power tools for architecture edition to give you more diagramming abilities in the designer:
  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5ef45ad4-336b-4a37-aded-ee9c9d8e6f8d&DisplayLang=en

**Edit:**  Apparently this was removed from VS2008.  If you have access to Visual Studio 2005, there are steps [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5ef45ad4-336b-4a37-aded-ee9c9d8e6f8d&DisplayLang=en) for reverse-engineering a 2008 project in 2005.

Comment: I apologize, this is apparently only true for VS2005... apparently the integration was removed in 2008??  Don't know why they would have done this, but the last time I used Visio was in VS2005, I assumed the ability would still be there.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947873%28VS.90%29.aspx